# I'm curious if this sentence is grammatically correct. Also, what kind of phrase is it called

Tags: grammar

> In the pocket of his shirt is a protein bar, soft from the sun,
>   uneaten, untouched, forgotten.

What is happening after *a protein bar*? Those aren't things in his shirt pocket; they are adjectives for the protein bar, I think.

Why are these adjectives following the noun? Why isn't there an *and* before the last adjective?

I searched *comma after noun before adjective* and further confused myself.

Comment: (a) Yes; what makes you curious that it might not be? (b) Which phrase are you referring to (there are three)? (c) What research have you done? Please [edit] your post to clarify points (b) and (c). For further guidance, see [ask] and take the EL&U **[Tour]**. :-)

Comment: @TinfoilHat - I think you've gone a bit far in editing this one.

Comment: @AndyT: Sorry, I'm new here. I tried to address Chappo's issues. Perhaps someone could fix the question so it passes review. It is an interesting one.

Comment: Should this question ever be reopened, I would answer it. Abstract: The things after *a protein bar* are [appositive adjectives](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-appositive-adjective-1688999), and the omission of *and* before the last adjective is a rhetorical act of [asyndeton](https://www.thoughtco.com/asyndeton-style-and-rhetoric-1689144)

Comment: I asked this question because I did not know. And I would be referring to the entire sentence put together. However, if you are able to break it down into three phrases, what would each of those three phrases be? I wondered about it not having an "and" before the last adjective, and if that made it grammatically incorrect. However, it seems to describe the protein bar and the rhetorical act of asyndeton makes sense. Why would someone write a sentence this way?